# Definition of finite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We can define a finite set $(\mathbb{X})$ like $ \exists  n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that there is a function $f : [n] \rightarrow \mathbb{X}$ where $f$ is bijective?

Or do we have to specify that $\mathbb{X} = \emptyset$?

Comment: What do you mean by $[n]$? The set $\{ 0, \ldots, n - 1 \}$? Then there is no need to treat $n = 0$ separately.

Comment: Should be $\exists n$, not $\forall n$.

Comment: @ZhenLin $[n]= \{ 0,1,...,n \}$

Comment: I guess your point is that despite the inclusion of $0$ in $\mathbb N_0$, we don't have a set of the form $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ that is empty, so we cannot form the bijection called for in your definition of "finite" to make $\emptyset$ satisfy the definition.  But your definition is not the usual one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $A$ is finite .
2. $f:A\to \mathbb{N_n} $ is bijective for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$
3. $A$ is not equivalent to any of it's proper subset.
4. No injective map from $A$ into $\mathbb{N} $ is onto.

It is our convention to take $|\emptyset|=0$

Comment: Your function $f$ not contain $\emptyset$ because $n$ cannot take the value zero. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A set is finite if every injective (resp. surjective) self-map is surjective (resp. injective).

Comment: But, that is the defenition of bijective. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Tino: It is not the definition of "bijective". It is a definition of "finite". You can use it to define "finite" in every category. Just replace "self-map" by "self-morphism". For example, finite dimensional vector spaces are finite in the category of vector spaces.

Comment: @Tino: So what? It is not related to my answer.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't answer my question. Although it helped a lot.

Comment: You asked for a "Definition of finite set"? It is the title of the question. The question body does not make sense. So I had to rely on the title.